# Can't get Stream Analytics with output Azure Function to work

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to have Stream Analytics as input to an Azure Function, but my Azure Function isn't being invoked. I am running out of ideas how to trouble-shoot.

The function is an HTTP Trigger function:

```
using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
     var content = req.Content;
    string jsonContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    log.Info(jsonContent);

    return   req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

The query in Stream Analytics looks like this:

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    [my-eventhub-03-dev]
FROM
    [my-iothub-01-prod];

SELECT
    *
INTO
    [my-api-function-001]
FROM
    [my-iothub-01-prod]
```

As you can see, I am also using en Event Hub as input, and messages are received by the event hub.

When adding the Azure Function as an output to the Stream Analytics job, the job performs an output test, which works fine, and I can see that call in the Azure functions log.
But, when I turn on the Stream Analytics job, messages only appear at the event hub, no calls to the Azure function. I have tried removing the Event hub, and removed that part of the query, resulting in:

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    [my-api-function-001]
FROM
    [my-iothub-01-prod]
```

That doesn't help either.

Any ideas how to proceed troubleshooting?

Thanks!
/Fredrik

Comment: What SSL are you using in Azure Function 1.0?
Maybe this is the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381267/connection-test-failed-when-trying-to-add-an-azure-function-as-an-output-sink-to/51492176#51492176

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what was wrong, but I created another Stream Analytics job, with identical configuration. That job works fine.