# Connection Test Failed when trying to add an Azure function as an output sink to Stream Analytics Job

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-stream-analytics

I always get a Connection Test Failed when trying to add an Azure function as an output sink to Stream Analytics Job.  The Azure function works fine by itself and I can also call it using Postman.  As soon as I add the Azure function, I get the Connection Test failed error message.
*Azure function returned an HTTP error.  An error occurred while sending the request.*

[image: Pic 1: Adding Azure function as output sink to Stream Analytics Job]

[image: Pic 2: Error message - Connection Test Failed]

Comment: Hi Milton, Sid from the Stream Analytics team here. Are you seeing a connection closed error? Can you share details of your ASA job to our Twitter handle (via DM) so we can investigate? https://twitter.com/AzureStreaming

Comment: Hi Milton, Katy from the Azure Functions team here. Can you share the following information so I can investigate the logs on our end: your function app's region, the app's name ([you can do so privately](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately)), and timeframe this happened in.

Comment: @KatyShimizu - Here is the information you requested...  2018-07-20T01:27:55.398 [Info] Function completed (Success, Id=d1e1bb57-0b79-4894-ba81-c80940a02eb6, Duration=1ms)

Comment: Thank you Milton. Can you also share the region your function app is deployed in?

Comment: @KatyShimzu - East US

Comment: Thanks again. Last request: what timeframe did your original issue occur in?

Comment: @KatyShimizu - Just tried it again on July 21, 12:53 AM EST...  Still fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue. 
The solution that works for me was to set up:

**Minimum TLS version: 1.0 (by default it was 1.2)**
for my function app.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks !!  Yes, once I tried your workaround, it mysteriously started working.  Changed it to Min TLS Version 1.0, then tried accessing using Postman (this was working before, but just wanted to make sure it was still working) and then tried from Stream Analytics Job (and voila, it worked !!).  Everything worked fine !!